# Buildbot Docker BUILDBOT_CONFIG_URL how to setup with SSH keys?

Tags: docker, ssh, key, buildbot

In the Buildbot Docker tutorial documentation it says:

*"You will need to change **docker-compose.yml** the variable **BUILDBOT_CONFIG_URL** in order to point to your github fork"*

But how would I do this if the URL points to a private repository accessible via SSH keys?

I can't seem to find an environment variable to specify the BUILDBOT_CONFIG_URL credentials.

An example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount ssh to get access under docker container.

Try to add next few lines into your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro
```